# Are questions about database design considered appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Would you consider questions about database design as appropriate for this website?

Answer (score 5):

Please see the list of answers on this question, I think it's what you're asking about, and that's starting to form the first FAQ here.

> [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators)