# Can the share on twitter linke automatically include #sqlhelp?

Tags: feature-request

The SQL Twitter community has done a great job self organizing around the [#sqlhelp hashtag](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23sqlhelp). I think it makes sense to add this hashtag to the default text of the share this question on twitter link on this site.

Comment: Sorry for downvote, I've answered below so you know my reasons for doing so.

Comment: No need to apologize for a downvote Jorge. People need to downvote more often. I don't think you should downvote intrinsically for a feature request you are against, but lots of people seem to think my thinking is wrong on this one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98582/can-the-twitter-link-on-public-betas-stop-the-title-before-140-chars-are-used Here you go.

Comment: @Justin ~ Try hovering over the downvote arrow on the meta. It says "or is not useful" and in this case, he thinks it is not useful. I don't either, but you showed me an intrinsic bug, so I forwarded it to Meta.SE for you. Also, on meta's, downvotes mean "I disagree" or "I don't want it" or "I don't like this" etc. Meta is not intended to generate rep either (hence the fact that votes here don't count) so downvotes are effectively free to both parties.

Comment: @jcolebrand, thanks for clarifying, and I'm glad my ignorance was tangentially useful in this case.

Comment: @JustinDearing don't call it ignorance. It was a valid and good question. I liked it. I'm also glad you helped us find a new bug in the system ;) [protip: I don't work for SEI in any capacity]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would recommend is - if you're going to have anything that automates any part of this - to have the 'share on twitter' button configured to always leave at least 9 charachters at the end of the tweet.  That way the person can add "#SQLHelp" at the end if they like.  I wouldn't recommend that it be placed there automatically because if every database Q&A site did that the #SQLHelp hastag could easily be flooded by posts.

The basics of "what is SQLHelp" can be summed up like this:

- It should be person-to-person or person-to-people communication focusing on **Questions & Answers**.
- By "communication" I mean quite simply that it should be bi-directional conversation.  Nothing post-only.  No drive-by dropping of links.
- Finally: **No Marketing!**  The only thing you should do to market yourself with the #SQLHelp hashtag (if marketing yourself is what your goal is) is to *just **help people***.

Hope this helps!  :-)

Comment: Yeah, having it foreshorten to less than 140 is good. I believe we might can work in a proper feature request on that.

Comment: Ok I'll concede that this is probably the best for the reasons everyone stated.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely advise against it as it would add a LOT of noise to the stream and defeat its purpose. If someone has a long question that can't be answered in 140 character bursts then we always recommend they create a forum question on a site like this or SSC, MSDN, etc. Auto posting would drive people insane and probably get you blocked by many of the folks. Just my $0.02 on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

I typically don't like to see the same question by the same person on multiple sites.  Pick on you like and trust and stick with it.  I hang out a lot on AskSSC and monitor #sqlhelp.  I just recently got asked to help out a bit on here as well.  I am in full agreement with the others who have posted saying BAD IDEA.  If you must, retype it.  Don't automate it.  Also if you happen to put it on twitter and on here and it gets answered on twitter, post the answer here, close your question, or delete it.  Don't cause multiple people to duplicate efforts when it isn't necessary.  Everyone is volunteering their time to help out.  Most sites are patrolled enough to get good coverage posting your question on a single site. Just my 2cents.

Comment: I'm personally good about making sure that the question gets answered on stackexchange if someone posts the reply directly to twitter. Then again I admit, not everyone is. I tend to share all my stackexchange questions on twitter, and #sqlhelp hashtag them when appropriate. Then again, I'm monitoring my twitter stream constantly, and I have a #sqlhelp column on my tweetdeck at home so it is a dialog for me.

Answer (score 3):

Why would every question / answer on here be about SQL?

It could be a question about NoSQL, LDAP, or [lots of other topics](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators) that may have nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: Excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

By spamming that hashtag on every question that gets posted (oracle or mysql jump out at me since I wouldn't think #sqlhelp would help them, but then again, idk) it's going to make it very difficult to keep getting good help for sql questions.

Additionally, as much as I like to toot the SE horn, there are other sites that are also setup on a similar model to this (but using OSQA or SE1.0) so that would be a negative mark against the SE for forcefeeding the Qs into the twitter stream.

However, I strongly encourage you to post them to twitter on your own when you ask a Q, and I have done it once already myself, bringing on a few new strong users.

FWIW: Further discussion here:

https://twitter.com/#!/SQLvariant/status/91213799192924163

https://twitter.com/#!/BrentO/status/91216768068096000

https://twitter.com/#!/BrentO/status/91218154050682880