# How do we define a question as being "too basic"? Where do we draw the line?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-definition

It [has been suggested](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/beginners-questions-convert-access-queries-and-such/307#307) that we close 'true beginner questions' as off-topic on this site.

Where do we draw the line? For example, should [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-table-using-foreign-key) be closed (I've voted to close it as off-topic, but want to know what others think about the general principle)

---

So the question has been refined to be: How do we know a question is too basic? Where are we drawing the line?

What are the key characteristics of "too basic"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've already answered that here: [Beginner's questions (convert Access queries and such)](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/beginners-questions-convert-access-queries-and-such/307#307) as you noted, and we also answered it here: [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators/)

Basic SQL questions are to be routed to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) or closed. Flag if you want them migrated (until the migration paths are setup for this site after launch).

Comment: I'm hoping people will volunteer their definition of "Basic SQL" - to see if there is consensus on "where do we draw the line"? the [other meta question](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators) focusses on what we want rather than what we don't want.

Comment: If you're asking how to use a basic verb, or you're describing a problem set without showing _any_ sql, then you're probably looking for [so]. If you can provide SQL and ask how to make it better, then you're probably looking for here. I concur tho, that we probably want better definitions as "what's off topic" so I'mma edit your post to that effect.

Comment: Perhaps change the second link to http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/11/21420 (now it links to a downvoted answer there).

Comment: I really meant the link to go to the Q >.>

Answer (score 5):

These are the areas that I think are too basic:

- Trouble parsing their SQL (syntax errors)
- Questions about ["pulling data from two tables"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/query-between-two-related-tables) (basic join questions)
- Converting queries from one [database to another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/how-do-i-convert-this-access-query-for-sql-server)

In my mind, any question about this should be directed to SO.