# Why are database developers' Q&A migrated to DBAs site

Tags: discussion, migration

The following link is an example:

[How SQL Server handles concurrent requests?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-sql-server-handles-concurrent-requests#6711296)

Why was it migrated to DBAs site? 
I think that at this time such questions get more exposure on stackoverflow. As such, they have a much better chance to get relevant answers.

I am not trying to make a blanket statement not to move anything. Some questions clearly belong here. Some other ones clearly belong over there on stackoverflow. The question I provided a link for is probably in a grey area.

I just think that developers probably need more education about concurrency than DBAs, because concurrency-related changes on the application side can have a huge impact on the database performance. As such, this particular question might help more readers if it is on stackoverflow. I might be wrong, of course.

Also I think the name of this site might be a show stopper for developers - many developers are not really likely to read answers on DBA's site.

Comment: Can you explain more *why* you think it's wrong? Isn't this advanced SQL more then general code monkeying? FYI, I flagged it for the move along with many others these last few weeks

Comment: Are you [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/author/alex-kuznetsov/) Alex Kuznetsov?

Comment: @JackDouglas: yes, the same chap. I've quoted Alex several times, especially the CHECK/UDF stuff

Comment: @JackDouglas that's me ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will attempt to answer this but it is very important to understand that SO is responsible for migrating questions here, not us.

From our point of view though:

- The question is [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) here (despite the name, we are not just for Database *Administration*)
- It is the kind of question that we have a track record of looking after well
- All three answers come from users who have profiles here on dba.se
- The top two answers come from users active on this site (and we'd love that to be the top 3)
- The top/accepted answer comes from our top user
- I believe it was flagged for migration by @gbn - so at least in his judgement, dba.se is a better home for the question (why not discuss it with him in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap)?)

These are just reasons why we are happy to accept the migration. My personal opinion is that the migration was correct, but my opinion [doesn't matter on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116717/166851) so if you are really against it, you will have to take it up with that site.

Comment: Jack, this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I like this answer and I'd like to add that Database Administrator (DBA) is a job classification applied to many different skill sets in the domain of data. Database developers are commonly referred to as Development DBAs and those who work in the more typical administration roles are sometimes referred to as Production DBAs.

Answer (score 4):

I wish all db related stuff would be migrated, at the moment you find same topics on both sites. That makes getting exposure and searching for things very inefficient. Would be nice if one selects the tag sql-server-2012 he will automatically sent to dba.stackexchange.com to post the question.